# Нет связывания с данными при генерации шаблона через цикл

Tags: vue.js

Хочу динамически сгенерировать форму на основе объекта посетителя.

```
<body>
<div id="enter-point">
    <template v-for="(detail, key) in visitor">

        <label>
        {{ key }}: <br>
        <input type="text"
               v-on:input="detail = $event.target.value"
               v-bind:value="detail"
               >
        </label>
        <br>

    </template>
</div>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#enter-point',
            data: {
                visitor: {
                    Email: '',
                    ['First Name']: '',
                    ['Last Name']: '',
                    Phone: '',
            },
         },
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

При этом изменения значений свойств объекта visitor (например visitor.Email при вводе строки в первый инпут) не происходит.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
В данном случае необходимо явно указывать привязку, т.е. примерно так: visitor[key].

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/L1L43ox5/2/

```
<div id="enter-point">
<template v-for="(detail, key) in visitor">
    <label>
    {{ key }}: <br>
    <input type="text" v-model="visitor[key]">
    </label><br>
</template>
<br>
```